# ffmpeg concat error

Tags: ffmpeg, command-line

I am trying to concatenate two video files using ffmpeg, and am receiving and error.

Two eliminate compatibility issues between the two videos, I am been concatenating the same video with itself, and the same error persists.

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i intro_prepped.avi intro_prepped.avi -c copy concat.avi
```

And the error output I receive is....

> [concat @ 0x220d420] Line 1: unknown keyword 'RIFFf�?'
>   intro_prepped.avi: Invalid data found when processing input

I have tried various combinations of concat flags and have not been able to get it to work. Has anyone seen this error before?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The concat demuxer expects a text file as input.

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i list.txt -c copy concat.avi
```

where list.txt is

```
file 'intro_prepped.avi'
file 'intro_prepped.avi'
```